# IntelliJ - is there any good Maven plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying IntelliJ 12 and one thing is really disappointing.... this is the maven integration.

I am missing following functionality:

- effective pom view
- search for particular jar trough dependency hierarchy
- classpath should be derived directly from maven pom, and not in some crazy random unknown way. I have the case now, where some dependencies are just omitted, and I can see them when executing `mvn dependency:analyze`
- changes is pom.xml are sometimes not reflected in project (classpath does not change, or has still old dependency and new one), also when I click "reimport"

Does anyone know some other maven plugin? Something like `m2e` would be really nice ;)

Comment: I don't have an answer to your actual question, but one way you can search for a particular jar in the hierarchy is to click on a pom in the Tool Window and select "Show Dependencies Popup".  In there you can search.

Comment: Is there search shortcut? When I directly type I need to provide full name which is not very useful.

Comment: Yeah if you press ctrl+f it gives you a search dialog.  Make sure to right click and select "actual size" first because it won't zoom in otherwise (pretty annoying).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I just moved from eclipse and my idea was, that there are many different plugins for single technology, well not in this case - case closed.

Answer (score 1):

As @tieTYT noticed, there is a 'Dependency popup' (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+U</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> works there).

Idea can automatically detect changes made to your pom.xml and apply them to project. To enable this, press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+A</kbd>, type 'maven auto', choose "Importing", checkbox "Import Maven project automatically";

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19582120/417846 for my answer. It at least provides a *relatively* easy way to get the effective pom.