# Dependency and Dependency viewer tab in intelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

Using STS when clicking on a pom.xml file I can view these tabs

```
Overview
Dependencies
Dependcy Hierarchy
Effective POM
pom.xml
```

How can I see all these tabs using intelliJ IDEA, specially Dependency Hierarchy? I tried to see it by `right click pom.xml > Maven > Show Dependencies`
but it only show a single rectangle having my project name in it...

Comment: Use the **Maven Projects** tool window, right click on the project, [Show Dependencies](http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/6218/20130413114737.png).

Answer (score 81):

To view effective pom you can right click your pom.xml > Maven > Show effective POM

[image]

Comment: When I do that, it says "Error: Failed to evaluate effective pom."

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way I have found to get the effective POM in IntelliJ is to add a maven run configuration with the following command:

```
help:effective-pom -Doutput=effective-pom.xml
```

This will create a file in your project folder called effective-pom.xml. If you need to update it, just run the configuration again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem so I checked my settings.xml's maven file and I realised I didn't have a "clean" `settings.xml` file because I have a custom mirror URL in place. The only way to fix this issue was to include [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47493222/922457) repositories and plugins in my `settings.xml` instead of the `pom.xml`; then, when I went to IntelliJ it started to load all dependencies. Once the previous process finished, I could see the Effective Pom file (by following @Ipandzic answer)