# How to know which tomcat version embedded in spring boot

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I used spring boot in project. It has inbuild tomcat server. I find out a jar `spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar`. I required to do certain tomcat related configuration on linux server.

How can I get to know which tomcat version used in this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Via http://search.maven.org/, in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-1.2.5.RELEASE.pom:

```
<tomcat.version>8.0.23</tomcat.version>
```

Comment: Ah, but this only works if you are using the Spring parent POM, if I'm not mistaken. What if you're pulling in the dependencies via imported dependency management as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent ?

Answer (score 46):

You can also check the version **without leaving your IDE** by seeing the effective pom.

For example, if you are using IntelliJ you can view effective pom by right clicking [pom.xml > Maven > Show effective POM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27035545/524588).

...or from the command line by issuing `mvn help:effective-pom`

Answer (score 10):

or For Gradle print the dependepency tree via the console with

```
./gradlew dependencies
```

Example snippet from output:

```
...
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.1.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.12
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.12
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.12
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.12
...
```

In my example above it is tomcat version `9.0.12`

Answer (score 6):

You can check the versions of all the dependencies in the dependency tree.

for that:

- go to the directory of pom.xml
- run the following command:

  $ mvn dependency:tree

  ```
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
  enter code here

  [INFO]
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Building {Project Name}
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO]
  [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ spring-mvc-logback ---
  [INFO] com.sj.common:spring-mvc-logback:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
  [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
  [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
  [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
  [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
  [INFO] |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
  [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
  [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
  [INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
  [INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile
  [INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
  [INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 0.937 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-19T19:17:54+08:00
  [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/308M
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```

And you will be able to watch all the dependencies and versions associated with that dependency.

Answer (score 5):

You can look at `http://mvnrepository.com/`:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.5.RELEASE

Below you have section `Compile Dependencies` and you can see that it uses `Tomcat 8.0.23`.

Comment: Thanks. If I search in linux with `where tomcat` no result found. why?

Comment: You meant whereis tomcat, right?

The tomcat embedded in spring boot is not a standalone tomcat deployed as an application in the operating system. It's just a jar that's added as a dependency in the pom. whereis finds files in the filesystem in some popular locations ($PATH, man path, source folders), not jars in ~/.m2/repository.

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse IDE:

1. Open your pom.xml
2. Go to "Effective POM" tab
3. Search for "tomcat"
4. Find `<tomcat.version>` line, for example: `<tomcat.version>9.0.27</tomcat.version>`

Answer (score 0):

For those who use PCF i.e. cloudfoundry

I generally keep spring boot tomcat dependency as provided
Which means my local tomcat version may be slightly different.

The java buildpack includes the tomcat version

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/releases

e.g. java buildpack 4.19.1 comes with Openjdk 1.8.0_212 and tomcat 9.0.19

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below snippet of your project's `pom.xml` wherein default parent is `spring-boot-starter-parent`

**Your project pom.xml**

```xml
<!--Spring boot parent project -->
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>2.4.5</version>
 <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Next lookup `pom.xml` of `spring-boot-starter-parent` project to see the dependencies, it has the `spring-boot-dependencies` as its parent. If using modern IDEs like IntelliJ/Vscode can easily traverse within IDE.

**spring-boot-starter-parent** pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.5</version>
</parent>
```

One level up again i.e., to `spring-boot-dependencies` it further doesn't have a parent, under properties all the defaults are listed. Sample snippet below having non exhaustive list showing only tomcat.

**spring-boot-dependencies** pom.xml

```xml
<properties>
  <!-- Other dependencies -->
  <tomcat.version>9.0.45</tomcat.version>
  <!-- Other dependencies -->
</properties>
```

This way, we can search for all the defaults out of the box.

Answer (score -2):

Print the dependepency tree via the console with

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: This is the same answer with another above, posted a year and a half ago.