# Maven fails to build the pom

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I downloaded a spring project from the spring initializer and imported it in sts via maven.

Unfortunately, build keeps failing, with this error:

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   com.dellteam:firstmicroservice:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer
>   artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.0.RELEASE
>   from/to spring-milestones (https://  repo.spring.io/milestone):
>   Connection reset and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

Please see below the `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dellteam</groupId>
    <artifactId>firstmicroservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>firstmicroservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

I thought my ISP is not allowing me to access `https://repo.spring.io/milestone/` but that is not the case.
This url is perfectly accessible to me.

I tried cleaning and building several times now and deleted **.m2 folder** and tried again rebuilding the project but the result is same.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured proxy in settings.xml????

Comment: No. Would you please help me on that ?

Comment: You can follow this link (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html), if you have any question do let me know.

Comment: Whenever i restart the sts, a pop up comes up and it asks for log on details for `proxy:80`. Do you think it has anything to do with this ? @Rezwan

Comment: have you provided username and password in the proxy setting. ca  please share settings.xml if possible

Comment: @Rezwan added a proxy. It Worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I have added answer for others as well. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an issue with your internet connection. Check if you need to configure a proxy server. You can set the proxies in settings.xml under your .m2 directory, check [This link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) for configuring proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Add Spring Plugin Release Repo to Plugin-Repositories. So that it can find the spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.0.RELEASE. 
Add the below lines under  tag as like:

```
<project>
  <!------ others lines -->
    <pluginRepositories>
     <pluginRepository>
        <id>repository.spring.release</id>
        <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
 </project>
```

For more info check --> [Spring boot starter parent 2.0.0 not found dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480451/spring-boot-starter-parent-2-0-0-not-found-dependency)

Comment: Added the same and went for maven `clean install compile`. Same issue persists.

Comment: try removing <relativePath/> tag , which is inside <parent> tag