# Not able to add parent tag in pom.xml maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Not able to add parent tag in pom.xml just like below. It keeps giving me an error saying "Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.2.RELEASE' not found
Inspection info: Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems." Could someone help please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
         <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.learning.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootApplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    </project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check first if repository is part of your project:

On [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.3.2.RELEASE), I see:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

So, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480852/6309), add:

```xml
<project>
<!------ others lines -->
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Or, in your case, a repository, as in [the same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48840004/6309):

```xml
    <repository>
        <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
        <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/</url>
    </repository>
```